# Trying to use ECS jenkins plugin for windows but unable to connect to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have setup jenkins on windows machine and setup amazon elastic container services.

I have installed "**Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin**" and trying to connect to create ECS slave node, but I am not able to do this.

> I am getting my node always offline.

Anyone is haveing any inputs on the same ??

Comment: try to if security group is blocking you ?

Comment: I have checked and its not blocking any communication.

Comment: I have checked and its not blocking any communication. I am trying below steps: 1. I have one jenkins EC2 windows dev machine and in the same VPC I have created ECS. 2. On Jenkins machine I have setup jenkins. 3. I have installed ""Amazon EC2 Container Service Plugin". 4. i have used https://blog.alexellis.io/continuous-integration-docker-windows-containers/ to create jenkins agent and used that while configuring ECS agent. 5. I am unable to run jobs on the ECS EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to many reasons, mainly configuration issues and I also experienced same.

3 main reasons.

1. On Docker image, you have to install Jenkins slave jar in correct location. It can be found https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/<version>/remoting-<version>.jar and should be installed "/usr/share/jenkins/"
2. AWS ECS cluster security group is having wrong inbound port setup, especially JNLP port. Configure it on Jenkins side (under Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security -> TCP port for JNLP agents and then fixed port number) as well as open it on AWS ECS side.
3. Use AWS ECS cluster container image from ECS optimize images than normal container images.